# How to convert a specific range of character cells in a dataframe to numeric?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data frame that I read in from excel like so:

[image: data frame]

I want to convert ONLY cells within the following range from 'character' to 'numeric': `df[2:17, 2:ncol(df)]`. I'm using ncol here as the number of columns will be unknown.

That's essentially everything excluding the first column, all the column headers (44449...2 eetc.) and the second row.

I have tried:

```
df[2:17, 2:ncol(df)] <- as.numeric(df[2:17, 2:ncol(df)])
```

But I get

```
Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I can't find the answer online. Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Apologies - its not clear from the image but the df has 17 rows (and this will not change)

Comment: Why aren't you changing the type of the first row? What's there?

Comment: All cells in that row contain characters and I need to keep them unchanged

Comment: Ah.  The correct but annoying answer is "don't do that" - we shouldn't mix data types within a data frame column.  Practically, I suggest removing the top row, doing the type conversion as per @ChrisRuehlmann 's suggestion below, then reattaching the top row when you need to export it.

Comment: Reshape your data, and make sure you have one header only, a column class can only be of one type and is therefor not cell specific, but column specific. It will make your analysing data far easier as well than sticking to a data frame in the "Excell format"

Comment: @G_Campbell, you may benefit from studying the principles of tidy data: `Tidy data is a standard way of mapping the meaning of a dataset to its structure. A dataset is messy or tidy depending on how rows, columns and tables are matched up with observations, variables and types. In tidy data:

Every column is a variable.

Every row is an observation.

Every cell is a single value.`

Comment: From: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html

Comment: as is, your data contains some categorical/descriptive data messing up a bunch of otherwise numeric variables. Since all columns can only have one data type, you get a mess. Dealing with this before any downstream analysis will help you much more than finding the hacky workaround you are asking for.

Comment: If this second row has important information about the variable, you may remove it and store it in a separated `list`

Comment: I also suspect you may have to transpose your data to a proper long format

Answer (score 1):

You can `mutate` `across` the column range in question to convert all values to numeric using `as.numeric`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(2:ncol(.)), ~as.numeric(.))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, appreciate the help. While it seems to have converted those characters to dbls, it has also turned all of the 2nd row into NA's (they have character strings and so I want to keep that row unchanged). Appreciate that wasnt clear from the image. Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: if there are values that are not (fully) numeric, they will always be converted to NA. If that pointer does not help do post some reproducible data so I/we can see what's going on...